# Having an issue while installing Kayako Fusion

Tags: php, magic-quotes-gpc

I am installing Kayako Fusion and get this error:

> Reason: Magic quotes is enabled in the php.ini configuration file. Please change magic_quotes_gpc to Off
>
> Unfortunately, Kayako cannot be installed. Either an error has occurred or your web server doesn't meet the minimum system requirements. Please review any errors shown above and retry the setup process after those items have been resolved

I have tried `php.ini` file also but its not working. I am on Shared Hosting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable magic quotes via .htaccess file

In the webroot of your Kayako install create a .htaccess file

paste in the following:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like something is overriding whatever customisations you are making to your php.ini. I think this is a question for your shared hosting provider: "How can I disable magic quotes for my hosting account?"

Hope this helps.